# PDF Editor/ Draw on PDF in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, swiftui, uikit

I'm looking for a solution to view and edit PDF files in a SwiftUI app. Above all, the functionality should be given to sign the PDF/ to draw on it. Is there any way to do this? I'm new to Swift development so I'm learning SwiftUI / UIKit at the same time. As a result, I have a hard time writing a wrapper for UIKit code in SwiftUI. My Code can display a PDF but cannot edit it so far:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import PDFKit


struct PDFKitView: View {
    var url: URL
    var body: some View {
        PDFKitRepresentedView(url)
    }
}

struct PDFKitRepresentedView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    
    init(_ url: URL) {
        self.url = url
        
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) -> PDFKitRepresentedView.UIViewType {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: self.url)
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        
        return pdfView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) {
        // Update the view.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found a solution. I used the PDFFreedraw Repo from ClassicalDude on GitHub. This is a well-implemented open source solution. I was then able to write a wrapper for swift UI like this.

https://github.com/ClassicalDude/pdfView-Freedraw

[Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbqDG.png)

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import PDFKit


struct PDFKitEditorView: View {
    var url: URL
    var body: some View {
        PDFKitEditorRepresentedView(url)
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}

struct PDFKitEditorRepresentedView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    let url: URL
    
    init(_ url: URL) {
        self.url = url
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainPDFView", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PDFViewControllerID") as? PDFViewController
        controller!.url = self.url
        
        return controller!
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
   
}
```